How detect collision between object1[i] and object2[j] then do something with them in Box2D games?
I am making a simple game with Box2D and SDL2.  I have GameObjects vectors for example: 1.vector of Enemy 2.vector of Bullets…
in ContactListener class i can detect collision between enemyFixture and bulletFixture. How i can detect contact between Enemy[i] with Bullet[j] and do something only with Enemy[i] or Bullet[j]?

It looks like the contact parameter passed to BeginContact allows you to access the two fixtures that are touching. From the fixture, you can reach the body each fixture is attached to. Both the body and the fixture allow you to attach "user data" such as the enemy or bullet index, or you could look those up from a hash table keyed on the body pointers. Did you run into trouble with any particular step in this process?
